# What's wrong with this simplest node.js module definition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't get node modules to work at all. This is my first time trying to do one. I'm used to Typescript modules only.

**m.js**

```
exports.msg = 'hello';
```

**app.js**

```
const m = require('m');
console.log(m.msg);
```

Why do I get this error?

`node app.js` gives me

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rje/projects/t/app.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

---

**Update** - the real problem: `viewhome.js` cannot see `config.js`

[image]

Comment: You need to require it with  a slash: `require('./m')` so that it doesn't look in the dependecies, but rather locally

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin you forgot a `.`, it should be `require('./m')`.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini yeah, thanks :) The point is that you need to require a local file relatively to your current file

Comment: Thanks guys. Ok, then node.js does work the way I expected. This was a test case to see why my real problem isn't working. Can you see anything wrong with the picture above please? I'm getting `module '../config' not found`

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, for example the error you got.

Comment: So when I run `node viewhome.js` I get the error `module '../config'` not found